# Replace Certain Words in Text With Link

Tags: php

I've a text like: `Added updates system. (Issue #20) (Alex)` and several others with the same format.

I want to replace `#20` to a link where I use 20 in the link. For example:

```html
Added updates system. (Issue #20) (Alex)
```

should be echo'ed like:

```html
Added updates system. (Issue <a href="http://tracker.website.com/view.php?id=20">#20</a>) (Alex)
```

The text is a whole, it's not parts. And I have an array of such texts that I want formatted in the same way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to replace numbers followed by a hash `#`:

```
preg_replace('/#(\d+)/', '<a href="http://tracker.website.com/view.php?id=$1">#$1</a>', 'Added updates system. (Issue #20) (Alex)');
```

Comment: no problem :) on facebook I read a status from a music teacher: "A student just asked me how to play F hashtag and C hashtag minor...words fail."